# Using Linq Retrieveing the data to SelectListItem

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have class studentList

```
 public class studentList
    {
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStudents(int? ID)
            {
//code is required here
    return ;
            }
        }
```

Iam getting ID into this method and now, I require all other IDs from the table, excluding the passed parameter ID using linq.

I have Student table which contains Two fieds StudentID and StudentName,
Now I require IDs and Names of the students in the above pattern..
Could any one help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might like to read : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

```
   var data= form s in Students
     where s.StudentID != ID
    select new {ID= s.StudenID,Name = s.StudentName};
```

image presentaion might be like

[image]